# Find all Palindromes in a String Using C

Tags: c, string, palindrome

I am trying to use C to print all Palindromes in a string and return the total number.

My code is returning all sorts of substrings which are not palindromes and printing blanks.

I am off by at least one in my printf statement formatting, but also, in my array element comparisons, it is working the opposite as I intended.

Can anyone see where I am going wrong?

Here is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

char x[1000];

void getString(char *n)
{
  printf("\nPlease enter your string: ");
  scanf("%s", n);
}

int findPals(char *s)
{
  int length = strlen(s);
  int numPals = 0;

  //find odd palindromes
  for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
  {
    for(int j = 0; j + i < length && i - j >= 0; j++)
    {
      if(s[i + j] != s[i - j])
        continue;
      else
      {
        numPals++;
        printf("%.*s\n", (j - i),s + i);
      }
    }
  }

  //find even palindromes
  for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
  {
    for(int j = 0; j + i + 1 < length && i - j >= 0; j++)
    {
      if(s[i + j + 1] != s[i - j])
        continue;
      else
      {
        numPals++;
        printf("%.*s\n", (j - i),s + i);
      }
    }
  }
  return numPals;
}

int main()
{
  char inStr[1000];
  int totalPals;

  getString(inStr);
  totalPals = findPals(inStr);
  printf("I found %d palindromes.\n", totalPals);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. I'm not sure I understand what you mean by 'all palindromes in a string'. Can you edit your question to include an example input string and what you expect to see as output, please?

Comment: @Nick OP wrote "substrings which are not palindromes" but I agree some examples would be good.

Comment: @WeatherVane, I don't understand what he is trying to do. I was accurately quoting from the first sentence of the question.

Comment: @Nick isn't it obvious? The whole string either is, or is not, a palindrome. So "all Palindromes" must be looking at substrings which is supported by the second sentence.

Comment: Your program didn't find the palindrome substring in the string I entered. Even when I entered "pop" it output rubbish. Time to wheel in the debugger? Aside; may the palindromes overlap?

Comment: [What should you do when someone answers your question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are only 2 small corrections required in your code (given below) other than that everything is fine:-

1.Continue statement in the array checking should be changed to break:

```
for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
{
  for(int j = 0; j + i < length && i - j >= 0; j++)
  {
    if(s[i + j] != s[i - j])
      break; // continue statement has been changed to break;
    else
    {
      numPals++;
      printf(".*s\n",(2*j)+1,&s[i-j]); // The length of the string has been modified
    }
  }
}
```

2. The string length in `printf` is incorrect.

For odd section use:

```
printf(".*s\n",(2*j)+1,&s[i-j]);
```

And for even section use:

```
printf(".*s\n",(2*j)+2,&s[i-j]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help. Here is my final program.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

char x[1000];

void getString(char *n) 
{
  printf("\nPlease enter your string: "); 
  scanf("%s", n); 
}

int findPals(char *s) 
{
  int length = strlen(s);
  int numPals = 0;

  //find odd palindromes  
  for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
  {
    for(int j = 0; j + i < length && i - j >= 0; j++)
    {   
      if(s[i + j] != s[i - j]) 
        break;
      else
      {   
        if ((j + j) > 1)
        {   
          numPals++;
          printf("%.*s\n", ((2 * j) + 1), &s[i - j]);
        }   
      }   
    }   
  }

  //find even palindromes
  for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
  {
    for(int j = 0; j + i + 1 < length && i - j >= 0; j++)
    {   
      if(s[i + j + 1] != s[i - j]) 
        break;
      else
      {   
        if ((j + j) > 1)
        {   
          numPals++;
          printf("%.*s\n", ((2 * j) + 2), &s[i - j]);
        }   
      }   
    }   
  }
  return numPals;
}

int main()
{
  char inStr[1000];
  int totalPals;

  getString(inStr);
  totalPals = findPals(inStr);
  printf("I found %d palindromes.\n", totalPals);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: BTW, This returns only palindromes with length greater than one.